# MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk

Tags: redis

i use reddison client but when the client has error “MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk”

```html
Unable to send PING command over channel: [id: 0x04130153, L:/171.20.0.8:38080 - R:10.3.236.102/10.3.236.102:6379]
org.redisson.client.RedisException: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.. channel: [id: 0x04130153, L:/171.20.0.8:38080 - R:10.3.236.102/10.3.236.102:6379] command: (PING), params: []
```

the redis server has no error

{"log":"3443340:C 09 Apr 00:12:41.648 * DB saved on disk\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-09T00:12:41.649083457Z"}
{"log":"3443340:C 09 Apr 00:12:41.772 * RDB: 38 MB of memory used by copy-on-write\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-09T00:12:41.77335587Z"}
{"log":"7:M 09 Apr 00:12:42.024 * Background saving terminated with success\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-09T00:12:42.025019006Z"}
{"log":"7:M 09 Apr 00:12:45.027 *

Answer (score -3, accepted):

beacuse the server time is not correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).